# Flag / star / reply icons overlap message border in chat

Tags: bug, chat, design

I've noticed that the dotted line (when hovering over a chat message) is 'broken' by the white background of the timestamp `div`.

[image: styling issue in chat]

So I tried to figure out what was causing this and I thought I had a fix. Add: `top: 1px;` to `.monologue .timestamp` and change `div.message .meta { right: 3px; }` to `div.message .meta { right: 1px; }`. Which seemed to work at first glance. So I logged in to SO using IE9 and that also fixed the issue there. So to be sure I booted up FF9 and went to chat without logging in only to find out that the issue is even 'messier' when you aren't logged in:

[image: styling issue in chat when not logged in]

So my first fix wouldn't be a real solution since the timestamp is just getting hidden by placing a background over it. But I still think we can add the:

```
.monologue .timestamp { top: 1px; }
```

This way the space above the timestamp div will be the same as the space of the right of the the timestamp div (`7px`). I know this sound like 'pixel fucking' and it is :-), but why not fix it while fixing the real issue. To resolve the real issue why not just set `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` on the timestamp div when hovering over a message on chat (instead of hiding it behind a background)?