# Teaser in chat a.k.a. chat post options overlap the message making links unclickable

Tags: bug, chat, design

When a link is shared in chat and it ends up in a specific position on the screen it is impossible to click it (without fiddling with the DOM).

[image: Interesting link]

As you can see in the printscreen above a link is in a post at the end of the line. However when I try to click the link the post options overlays the link (once I hover over the post):

[image: FFFFFFFFFUUUUUUUU]

- Link to transcript: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/12993943#12993943
- Resolution: 1366 x 768 (laptop)
- Browser: Chrome v3300 (by the time you read this it will be at that version)

Comment: +1. For freehand circles

Comment: Can you link to transcript with example?

Comment: Also, isn't it the same bug as [the one reported here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120201/152859)?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Nope. Not really. Kinda. Maybe. At least my fix there would not fix this issue. That issue was more about ugly alignment and overlapping the timestamp. This issue actually overlaps "normal" text in chat.

Comment: Well, no repro here maybe because no action buttons in transcript.